# Proving $\|L\| = \sup\left\{\frac{\|L(x)\|}{\|x\|}\colon x\ne 0\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Can I please get feedback on my proof below? It is a problem from Bartles' Analysis book. Thank you!

$\def\x{{\mathbf x}}
\def\0{{\mathbf 0}}
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}
\def\R{{\mathbb R}}$

The norm of a transformation $L\in{\mathcal L}(\R^n,\R^m)$ is defined by
$$\|L\| = \inf\{C\colon \|L(\x)\|\le C\|\x\|\ \mbox{for all}\ \x\in\R^n\}.$$
Prove that
$$\|L\| = \sup\left\{\frac{\|L(\x)\|}{\|\x\|}\colon \x\ne\0\right\}.$$

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Given $\|L\| = \inf\{C\colon \|L(\x)\|\le C\|\x\|\ \mbox{for all}\ \x\in\R^n\}$, lets say it equals to $\alpha$. We wish to prove that $\|L\| = \sup\left\{\frac{\|L(\x)\|}{\|\x\|}\colon \x\ne\0\right\}$ equals to $\beta$. So, it is sufficient to prove that $\alpha = \beta$. From, our definition of $\beta$, for $\x\ne \0$ $$\frac{\|L(\x)\|}{\|\x\|} \le \beta \text{ implies } \|L(\x)\| \le \beta\|\x\|$$ and $\alpha$ is the infimum of all such constant C such that $\|L(\x)\| \le C\|\x\|$. Therefore, $\alpha \le \beta. \hspace{8 pt} (1)$

Now, suppose $D$ is such that $\alpha < D$. By definition there is some $C$ with $\alpha \le C < D$ such that $\|Lx\| \le C \|x\| \le D \|x\|$ for all $x$.

Then $\beta \le D$. Hence $\beta \le \inf\{ D | \alpha < D\} = \alpha. \hspace{8pt} (2)$

By (1) and (2), we arrive at $\alpha = \beta$ so $$\|L\| = \|L\| = \sup\left\{\frac{\|L(\x)\|}{\|\x\|}\colon \x\ne\0\right\}.$$

We can also prove this by letting $$\alpha = \inf\{C\colon \|L(\x)\|\le C\|\x\|\ \mbox{for all}\ \x\in\R^n\} = \inf\{C\colon \frac{\|L(\x)\|}{\|\x\}} \le C, \x\ne \0\}.$$ Therefore $\alpha$ is the infimum of the set of all upper bounds of $$\left\{\frac{\|L(\x)\|}{\|\x\|}\colon \x\ne\0\right\}$$ where $\alpha$ is the supremum of the set $$\left\{\frac{\|L(\x)\|}{\|\x\|}\colon \x\ne\0\right\}.$$ Therefore, $\alpha = \beta$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't follow your logic showing $\beta \le \alpha$.

Suppose $D$ is such that $\alpha < D$. By definition there is some $C$ with $\alpha \le C < D$ such that $\|Lx\| \le C \|x\| \le D \|x\|$ for all $x$.

Then $\beta \le D$. Hence $\beta \le \inf\{ D | \alpha < D\} = \alpha $.

Comment: Thank you. I made the adjustment. Does it look fine now?

Comment: Hmm, not really, your original proof of $\alpha \le \beta$ was perfect. The above part starting with "Again, we..." is what I found difficult to follow.

Comment: Oh wow, I see now. I made the edit, sorry about that. I hope it is clear now?

Comment: Looks good now!